# cf push without a manifest file

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a nodejs application without a mainfest file as follows(using cloud foundry push command):

`cf push appname -c "node app.js" -d "mydomain.net" -i 1 -n hostname -m 64M -p "path to directory" --no-manifest`.

This works on Windows. However, if I run the same on Linux, it throws me `"incorrect"` usage. Is there any difference w.r.t. **"double quotes"** or what might be the issue?

Comment: Do you have the same version of cf in both your Windows and Linux systems? Also could you please put the complete error output when you run command in Linux?

Comment: .Thank you very much for the response.Yes, I was using the same version, but the problem was I was using a java exec to run the cf command. It was causing  a issue because of the double quotes.So I changed my cf push to accept parameters both from manifest file. It is working fine now.